# BeautifulSoup4 "class_" - no found documentation

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I am struggling with "no documentation found" problem, on `class_`.

I have installed everything using `pip install beautifulsoup4`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Request the page and parse the HTML
url = 'mywebsite'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

#Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
soup.find_all('div', class_="content_class")
```

[image: here is my BS version]

[image: example]

Comment: because it doesn't have any documentation in code, at least I didn't see any, maybe they have sth about it on website or github but really it is just the name of the html attribute with an added underscore because `class` is a built-in name

Comment: Is it _really_ easier to make a screenshot, save it and [post in the question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) then copy & paste the code..?

Comment: also, read on [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kwargs)

Comment: i have posted my code

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax of using it is wrong. Here's how you should use it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Request the page and parse the HTML
url = 'mywebsite'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

#Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
soup.find_all('div', {'class_' :"content_class"})
```

You can also put `class` in place of `class_` if you want but it's literally the same thing :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Request the page and parse the HTML
url = 'mywebsite'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

#Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
soup.find_all('div', {'class' :"content_class"})
```

Comment: `class_` can also be used, it is not wrong, literally the same thing, it is just a keyword argument

Comment: Your solution is incorrect. Considering editing it. `soup.find_all('div', {'class_' :"content_class"}) ` will only work if the tag has that specific attribute, Ie `<div class_="content_class">`. It won't find `<div class="content_class">`

Answer (score 0):

But does the code raise an error when you run it?

As of Beautiful Soup 4.1.2, you can search by CSS class using the keyword argument class_

So `soup.find_all('div', class_="content_class")` should work provided bs4 the correct version.

Otherwise, you can use the other syntax of `soup.find_all('div', {'class':"content_class"})`. That should work regardless of the version.

Comment: Thanks. Thanks to you i discovered even if error is shown, code works fine..

Comment: That's not an error.